# Git set tracking branch while offline

Tags: git

`git push -u origin branch`

binds *branch* with *origin/branch* so that subsequent pushes from *branch* can be just `git push`, as far as I understand.

Can I set up this kind of tracking for a brand new repo (*origin/branch* doesn't exist yet) while offline? I want to make it so all subsequent pushes from *branch* go to *origin/branch* without me having to specify that when I go online.

Comment: As in, you want to add a new branch on the remote machine while your local machine is offline?

Comment: I want all the subsequent pushes from `branch` to go to `origin/branch` without having to specify that when I go online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use `xyz` as the name of the branch and keep `origin` as the name of the remote to avoid confusion. You already mentioned the *online* method to push and set upstream at the same time..

```
git push --set-upstream origin xyz
```

### Fetch online, set upstream offline

The preferred way would be to fetch the branch before going offline and using `--set-upstream-to` option of `git branch` to set upstream without pushing.

```
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/xyz
```

That results in adding the following lines to `.git/config` which is also the result of the *online* way described before.

```
[branch "xyz"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/xyz
```

### Fully offline approach

When you don't want to fetch the remote branch first, you can either edit `.git/config` by hand or use the `git config` facility to perform the same action.

```
git config branch.xyz.remote origin
git config branch.xyz.merge refs/heads/xyz
```

When you then fetch the remote branch, you should have reached the same result as with `--set-upstream-to` with remote branch already fetched.

### Alternative offline approach

You can instead mimic the fetch offline by setting the remote branch ref to a specific commit, e.g. to the same commit as your local branch.

```
git update-ref refs/remotes/origin/xyz xyz
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/xyz
```

The idea of direct ref updating is borrowed from Decave's answer. Use with care and read [`git-fetch(1)`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) notes about fast-forward/non-fast-forward fetches.

Comment: Sweet. Děkuji pěkně! If I wanted to set xyz to track abc on remote, I'd just do `merge = refs/heads/abc`, correct?

Comment: _Use with care_. Why? You're just adding a reference to a branch. It's not a dangerous operation.

Comment: Also, your answer is broken. You need to run `--set-upstream-to` after adding the remote ref.

Comment: @PSkocik: Yes, you can use any values instead of `origin` and `xyz`. @Decave: Updated according to both of your comments. Any comments on the non-fast-forward fetch?

Comment: @Decave: Sorry for killing your edit suggestions by making my own new edits, I failed to see them. If there's still anything to edit, I'll try to avoid doing it again.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, let's hack ourselves some `git`.

The place where `git` stores references to remote branches is in `.git/refs/remotes/<remote_repo>`. Let's say that we had just created a new repo, and added remote as an origin. Then we go offline and create a new branch called `new_branch`.

If you take a look in `.git/refs/remotes/origin` you should see:

```
decave@demo~$ls /home/decave/demo/.git/refs/remotes/origin
HEAD
```

There are no branches in there; which is to be expected given that we haven't pushed or pulled any branches from the remote repo. Now, let's say `new_branch` was pointing at a commit with hash `e81d5ea59b5f7ab81de4662f7dca5de86e230d92`. If we add a file to `.git/refs/remotes/origin` called `new_branch` with its contents set to `e81d5ea59b5f7ab81de4662f7dca5de86e230d92`, then it would be equivalent to telling your local repo "hey, `new_branch` is a branch on origin that points to the commit `e81d5ea59b5f7ab81de4662f7dca5de86e230d92`". This can be accomplished with the `git` plumbing command `git update-ref`:

```
git update-ref refs/remotes/origin/new_branch e81d5ea59b5f7ab81de4662f7dca5de86e230d92
```

Then, if you run the command

```
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/new_branch
```

It should successfully configure `git` to do what you want.

Note that this it's pretty terrible practice to start plumbing around your own repository like this. The proper way to make this happen would just be to use the `-u` flag like you said.

Comment: How would you provide a tool for tracking an object that doesn't exist in the object store?

Comment: What happens when you run `git branch --set-upstream-to <branch>` is git checks the object store on your local repository for that branch. If it doesn't find it, there's absolutely no way for it to track it.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda I changed my answer to show how you could mercilessly hack `git`. Can I have my upvote back please?

Comment: What is unclear about it? First I introduce the directory where references to the remote branches live, then I explain how to add a reference to a non-existent remote branch and what that means, and lastly how to apply this change to get the desired results. In your answer you just gave some opaque config commands and didn't explain how or why `git` is able to track the branch as a result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79455/discussion-between-decave-and-pavel-simerda).

Comment: My answer takes the same number of commands as @PavelŠimerda's -- two. It also provides more clarity into why `--set-upstream-to` doesn't work without a reference to the remote branch. His answer is even more hacky because it relies on `git` to assume people may have ran non-sensible config commands that referenced non-existent branches.

Comment: His answer is a hack too -- and the reason is that what you're trying to do is ridiculous and hacky

Comment: It's not like I don't appreciate your answer but IMO, there's no reason you should have to go online to set this up. Won't your solution break when I try to fetch the remote? It seems like Pavel's won't.

Comment: You don't have to be online to set up the reference to the remote branch if you already have it locally. I think it makes perfect sense that you should have to be online when you fetch a reference to a remote branch that you *don't* have locally. And no, this will not break.

Comment: That reference is just for `git status` to show how you fare in comparison to the remote, no? If I'm offline, that's something I can do without. Tracking is just about comparing branches and having an implicit target for pushes (fetches?). I think it makes sense it should be settable offline. (BTW, you have my upvote too -- I just like Pavel's answer better 'cause it's cleaner and scriptable (magic commit hashes aren't)).

Comment: What? No. `git status` doesn't compare your changes to the remote branch, it compares them to the previous commit for the local branch. The remote reference branch is used to reference the branch on the remote repository...which may point to a different commit than your local one. I don't think it makes any sense whatsoever to set it offline to be honest. And you can script it using my approach too. Just use the name of the branch instead of the hash. You're free to accept whichever answer you choose -- I just don't think you guys had good reason to call my answer hacky.

Comment: Either way, it's an interesting question. Thank you for the upvote

Comment: git status also shows how you compare to the remote. I think that's what tracking is all about (+the implicit push targets). Your answer is nice, LOL. Indeed, I did not have a good reason to call it hacky. That's why I had deleted that comment almost immediately afterwards. No need to get upset about what some random guy on the internet thinks or says.

Comment: No, you're thinking of `git diff`

Comment: If your current branch has a tracking branch, `git status` shows you if you're up-to-date with it, behind, in front, or if the branches have diverged.