# How do I set git up to automatically configure the upstream on a branch

Tags: git

I am always pushing my code to the same upstream repo. I would like to set up git so that when I create a new branch with `git checkout -b foo`, the upstream for branch `foo` will automatically push to and pull from the branch `foo` on the `origin` repo.

Is this possible?

Comment: One problem: `git checkout -b foo` creates and checks out a new branch called `foo`. How can you be sure, at the time of creating that branch, that a branch called `foo` already exists on `origin`?

Comment: On the other hand, if the remote-tracking branch `origin/foo` exists, you can simply run `git checkout -b foo origin/foo`, which will do what you want, i.e. set the upstream of the local `foo` branch to `origin/foo`.

Comment: Jubobs, I'm gonna try putting that in my git alias

Comment: Good call, if that's convenient for you. Have a look at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847213/how-to-configure-git-push-to-automatically-set-upstream-without-u

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git set tracking branch while offline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602769/git-set-tracking-branch-while-offline)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I need to do \`--set-upstream\` all the time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089294/why-do-i-need-to-do-set-upstream-all-the-time)